# NXT not updating, "Cannot locate NXT device to download firmware!"

Tags: nxt, bluetooth

[image: "Cannot locate NXT device to download firmware"]

I am using a Bluetooth connection trying to update firmware from 1.05 to 1.31 and it displays the message:

> Cannot locate NXT device to download firmware!

My NXT works fine other than that. I got it from a thrift store will so I don't know much about its history and I don't have a USB connector. I don't know what to do.  What should I try next?

Comment: I advise that you reboot the brick and even the software itself if necessary. It's likely that the brick is defective. Try using WiFi or USB if that doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot update the NXT firmware over Bluetooth, you need a USB cable like the found on most printers.